# How to shorten the GPLv3 text

Tags: gpl-3, github, license-notice

The question is simple: How should I shorten the text of GNU GPLv3 (674 lines) for adding it to the top of all the source files in a repository?

As an example, here is a piece of text added to the top of a source file in [Kdenlive repository](https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive):

```
/*
    SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2017 Nicolas Carion
    SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only OR LicenseRef-KDE-Accepted-GPL
*/
```

Is there an appropriate format for writing such a piece of text for every source file? And is it necessary to add it to the files?

Comment: If you're asking about what text to include at the top of each source file to let people know that it's under the GPL, have you read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/7682/458)?  Or are you asking specifically about [SPDX identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Package_Data_Exchange), in which case, could you maybe change the title and first paragraph to make that clearer?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, I think it's got the necessary info. Tnx.

Comment: Thanks for checking!  In that case, may I close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes please go on and close it.